# Are there technical issues/disavdantages on this BaseService that aims to simplify calling API endpoints

Tags: typescript, angular-2+

I have created an angular BaseService that aims to simplify calling API endpoints

I would like to know if you see any code smells, bad patterns or architecture issues.
What disadvantages could this have.

The idea is to decouple the api configuration from the implementation

The configuration is made in the `api-config.ts`

```js
export enum ENDPOINT {
    CONFIGURATION_GET_MENU = 0,
    CONFIGURATION_GET_MINUTE_OFFSET,
    APPOINTMENT_GET_ADV_TYPES,
    APPOINTMENT_GET_ADV_DOMAIN_GROUPS,
    APPOINTMENT_GET_ADV_EXISTING_DATA,
    APPOINTMENT_DELETE_ADV,
    DASHBOARD_GET_NOSHOW_DATA,
}

export enum VERB {
    GET,
    GET_BY_PARAMS,
    POST_BODY,
    POST_BODY_PARAMS,
    PATCH,
}

export class ApiConfig {
    endpoint: ENDPOINT;
    url: string;
    verb: VERB;
}

const API_CONFIG: ApiConfig[] = [
    {
        endpoint: ENDPOINT.CONFIGURATION_GET_MENU,
        url: '/cfg/getMenu',
        verb: VERB.GET
    },
       {
        endpoint: ENDPOINT.CONFIGURATION_GET_MINUTE_OFFSET,
        url: '/cfg/getCSMO',
        verb: VERB.GET_BY_PARAMS
    },
    {
        endpoint: ENDPOINT.APPOINTMENT_UPSERT_ADV_TYPES,
        url: '/aat/post',
        verb: VERB.POST_BODY
    },
    {
        endpoint: ENDPOINT.APPOINTMENT_DELETE_ADV,
        url: '/aat/delete',
        verb: VERB.PATCH
    }
    {
        endpoint: ENDPOINT.DASHBOARD_GET_NOSHOW_DATA,
        url: '/dsh/getCNSD',
        verb: VERB.POST_BODY_PARAMS
    }
];


export { API_CONFIG as API_CONFIG };
```

Then the `baseService` exposes a `call` method that determine what verb needs to be called and is the only place where httpClient is used

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ConfigService } from 'src/app/app-config.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
import { ApiConfig, API_CONFIG, ENDPOINT, VERB } from './api-config';

class CallOptions {
    body?: any;
    params?: HttpParams;
    queryString?: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class BaseService {

    constructor(protected httpClient: HttpClient, private configService: ConfigService) { }

    public call(apiEndpoint: ENDPOINT, opt: CallOptions): Observable<any> {

        const verb = this.getConfig(apiEndpoint).verb;

        switch (verb) {
            case VERB.GET:
                return this.get(apiEndpoint);
            case VERB.GET_BY_PARAMS:
                return this.getWithParams(apiEndpoint, opt.params);
            case VERB.PATCH:
                return this.patch(apiEndpoint, opt.queryString, opt.params);
            case VERB.POST_BODY:
                return this.post(apiEndpoint, opt.body);
            case VERB.POST_BODY_PARAMS:
                return this.postWithParams(apiEndpoint, opt.body, opt.params);
            default:
                const error = `BaseService: Verb ${verb} not supported yet`;
                console.log(error);
                throw new Error(error);
        }
    }
    //TODO if migration is finished convert this to private, it should not fail compiling
    protected getBaseUrl(): string {
        return this.configService.get('apiUrl');
    }

    private getConfig(apiEndpoint: ENDPOINT): ApiConfig {
        const apiConfigEndpoint = API_CONFIG.find(e => e.endpoint === apiEndpoint);
        if (apiConfigEndpoint === undefined) {
            const error = `BaseService: Endpoint (${apiEndpoint}) not configured`;
            console.log(error);
            throw new Error(error);
        }
        return apiConfigEndpoint;
    }

    private buildURL(apiEndpoint: ENDPOINT) {
        return `${this.getBaseUrl()}${this.getConfig(apiEndpoint).url}`;
    }

    private get(apiEndpoint: ENDPOINT): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.buildURL(apiEndpoint));
    }

    private getWithParams(apiEndpoint: ENDPOINT, params: HttpParams): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.buildURL(apiEndpoint), { params });
    }

    private post(apiEndpoint: ENDPOINT, body: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.buildURL(apiEndpoint), body);
    }

    private postWithParams(apiEndpoint: ENDPOINT, body: any, params: HttpParams): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.buildURL(apiEndpoint), body, { params });
    }

    private patch(apiEndpoint: ENDPOINT, queryParams: string, params: HttpParams): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.patch<any>(`${this.buildURL(apiEndpoint)}?${queryParams}`, params);
    }
}
```

Since the call method returns an `Observable` it can be used in the same places and in the same way as when calling httpClient get or post methods

```js
loadMenu$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(actions.loadMenu),
        switchMap(() => this.baseService.call(ENDPOINT.CONFIGURATION_GET_MENU, {})
            .pipe(
                map(response => actions.loadMenuComplete({ menu: response.result })),
                catchError(() => of(actions.loadMenuFailure({ error: 'fail' })))
            )
        )
    ));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating a client for the API, try to avoid magic strings as much as you can.
You will have problems with calls like this:

```
// PRODUCT_CREATE = "/users/:userId/lists/:listId/products"
client.call(PRODUCT_CREATE, body, {userId: 1, listId: 1})
```

Client would be much easier and safe to use like with an interface like this:

```
client.users.getProducts({someParams})
// OR
client.users.addProductToList(body, {someParams})

// this is an example class - having users as an object seems ugly, but you can easily
// create it as a separate class
class Client {
  public users = {
    addProductToList: (body: Product, params: {userId: number, listId: number}) => {...}
  }
}
```

With this you gain type safety - if you will ever change your config, you will not know, what needs to change and what will fail.

```
// PRODUCT_CREATE = "/products"
client.call(PRODUCT_CREATE, body)
```

If the endpoint changes, the above call compile, but will fail at runtime, because the parameter was not provided:

```
// SOME_ENDPOINT = "/users/:userId/products"
client.call(PRODUCT_CREATE, body) // missing {params}
```

The same goes for get requests. If you are using TS, use it, because having config in a json file will lead to more headaches than it will solve. Your endpoint enum will also grow out of control and will have no hierarchical order -> it will be hard to reason about.

If you have enum in code, you have coupled yourself already. Why not just make each enum value a method with correct parameters?

Edit: hopefully this will be more clear what I mean when I talk about type safety:

You are basically spreading the logic of the client across your whole codebase. I suppose you wouldn't want to have code that looked like this:

```
enum Methods {
  USER_CREATE = "createUser"
}

class UserService {
  private users: User[]

  invoke(method: Methods, params: {[key: string]: any}) {
    this[method](params)
  }

  private createUser(params: {[key: string]: any}) {
    this.users.push({id: params.id, name: params.name, ...})
  }
}
```

Well, that is basically what you are proposing. You are moving method names to the config. It would be way easier if you structured the client differently and used actual methods and typed parameters for those methods.

```
interface UserDto {
  name: string
  age: number
}

class Users {
  constructor(..., private path: (url: string) => string) {}

  createUser(user: UserDto) {
    this.http.post<UserDto>(this.path("users"), user)
  }
}

class Products {
  ...

  getById(params: {userId: number, productId: number) {
    // I am not sure of the correct use of the http call with parameters, 
    // but it would be something along the lines of:
    this.http.get<Product>(this.path("users/:userId/products/:productId"), params)
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class ApiClient {
  users: Users
  products: Products

  private baseUrl = 'https://.../v1/'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.users = new Users(http, this.path)
    this.products= new Products(http, this.path)
  }

  private path(url: string): string {
    return this.baseUrl + url
  }
}
```

Then you would have such calls to this client:

```
// somewhere
apiClient.users.createUser({name: "user", age: 33})

// somewhere else
apiClient.users.createUser({name: "user", age: 33})

// somewhere else 2
apiClient.users.createUser({name: "user", age: 33})


// somewhere else 3
apiClient.users.createUser({name: "user", age: 33})
```

If you ever changed the url, you would do it in one place: createUser method. If you ever changed the parameters, you would do it in one place: createUser method.

```
  interface UserDto {
    firstName: string // we split the name into first and last name fields
    lastName: string
    // we don't need user's age anymore
    height: number // we decided to collect user's height
  }

  createUser(user: UserDto) {
    // changed the endpoint path
    this.http.post<UserDto>(this.path("happyUsers"), user)
  }
```

Now the usages look like this:

```
// somewhere
apiClient.users.createUser({firstName: "user", lastName: "last", height: 2})

// somewhere else
apiClient.users.createUser({firstName: "user", lastName: "last", heigt: 2})

// somewhere else 2
apiClient.users.createUser({firtName: "user", lastName: "last", height: 2})

// somewhere else 3
apiClient.users.createUser({name: "user", age: 33})
```

If we would try to run the above code the compilation would fail for 3 of the 4 calls. Did you spot them when you looked at the code at first?

```
// good
apiClient.users.createUser({firstName: "user", lastName: "last", height: 2})

// bad: typo in height
apiClient.users.createUser({firstName: "user", lastName: "last", heigt: 2})

// bad: typo in firstName
apiClient.users.createUser({firtName: "user", lastName: "last", height: 2})

// bad: forgot to change
apiClient.users.createUser({name: "user", age: 33})
```

Here is what happens when path parameters change:

```
  createUser(user: UserDto, params: {session: string}) {
    // changed the endpoint path - it is a stupid change, but it is just to illustrate the point
    this.http.post<UserDto>(this.path("session/:session/happyUsers"), user, params)
  }
```

```
apiClient.users.createUser({firstName: "user", lastName: "last", height: 2}, {session})

apiClient.users.createUser({firstName: "user", lastName: "last", height: 2}, {session})

apiClient.users.createUser({firstName: "user", lastName: "last", height: 2}, {sesion})

apiClient.users.createUser({name: "user", age: 33}, {session})
```

Third call will fail, because there is a typo in session. These are just some examples of what can go wrong if you do not use the type system. Imagine having dtos that have 10-20 fields. The typos would be way harder to spot, especially if there are also nested fields involved.

Also, if your endpoint change rarely, it is another reason for you to hardcode them in the methods and not have them as configuration.

Comment: the idea of `CallOptions` is to provide flexbility and avoid the need to adding/removing parameters to each call to the API - if you are changing the ENDPOINT and the parameters of the backend is your responsability to change BOTH in the front end. With your design this still happens since I would have to add or remove paremeters to match the new ENDPOINT

Comment: The order of the JSON would depend on how you add elements to it , if you see my question all the APPOINTMENT_* endpoints are together, you consider is better to grow out of control sparsed in different files/folder than in a single place ?

Comment: Yes, I'm not saying that it does not happen, but like I said, you lose type safety. Imagine having calls spread across the code - maybe at 5 different places. You change the backend, and add a new parameter. Now you have to change the front end - you will have to add a parameter in 5 different places. What are the chances that you forget to add a parameter in one place? It is high. In my implementation you can lean back on the type system, as it will report errors at compile time.

Comment: The ENUM does not need to know what are the right parameters, the enum exist just as a replacement to avoid using STRINGS directly in call (1 level of abstraction). If you show me how to declare an enum and useit in a single place, that would be cool.

Comment: That your endpoints are together is my exact point. You are using hierarchy already, but in a flat state. Why not make it {apointment: {...apointmentEndpoints}}? And why use json, when you can do this in code that can leverage types?

Comment: forgetting adding parameters is always something that can happen, with your proposal or with mine, because in your proposal you still need to specify how many parameters are needed to make certain call, what if you forget to the 5th parameter in there ? it would compile but it will fail at runtime

Comment: The JSON was just an IDEA is not implemented in my proposal. You propose to group certain endpoints and just join them all together like you mentioned ?

Comment: I'll give you another example, it might be easier to understand. And look if you really want to try your approach, do it, but it will cause you headaches that could have been avoided leveraging typescript. The reason why javascript is "bad" is because you don't know what will break and where after refactoring.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126700/discussion-between-mauricio-gracia-gutierrez-and-blaz-mrak).

Comment: I have made more comments to you in the chat, look forward for the more detail {apointment: {...apointmentEndpoints}} example

Answer (score 1):

It seems a bit odd to me that `ApiConfig` lives separately from the service. Isn't the set of available endpoints a property of the service? `some_service.call(endpoint_definitions[endpoint_name], some_parameters)` feels less natural to me than `some_service.endpoint_definitions[endpoint_name].call(some_parameters)`

I also find the type of `ApiConfig` a bit odd. The `API_CONFIG` enum values should uniquely identify the various endpoints, right? Couldn't that be enforced by making it a `Map<ENDPOINT, { url : string; verb : VERB; }>` instead of a `{ endpoint : ENDPOINT; url : string; verb : VERB; }[]`?

It also seems to me like API endpoints with different verbs are not interchangeable in terms of how they can be used, but the `CallOptions` class seems almost designed to hide that. Calling a `POST_BODY` endpoint with `CallOptions` designed for a `GET` endpoint or vice versa is wrong by definition. That's the kind of thing type errors were invented to find. To me it feels pretty natural to define a family of types like

```
interface GetEndpoint {
    verb: VERB.GET;
    url: string;
    call: () => Observable<any>;
}

interface PostEndpointWithParams {
    verb: VERB.POST_PARAMS;
    url: string;
    call: (HttpParams) => Observable<any>;
}

// etc

type Endpoint = GetEndpoint | /* various others | */ PostEndpointWithParams
```

Or, alternatively, maybe something like

````
type CallTypes = {
    "GET": () => Observable<any>;
    "POST": (body: any) => Observable<any>;
    "POST_WITH_PARAMS": (body: any, params: HttpParams) => Observable<any>;
}

interface Endpoint<V extends keyof CallTypes> {
    url: string;
    verb: V;
    call: CallTypes[V];
}
```
````

Comment: Very nice comments thanks below I will address them below

Comment: At the end of your answer : Linking the CallTypes to how each calltype is implemented makes it more reliable and even readable

Comment: If you are calling a `POST_BODY` endpoint with `GET` varb is just a configuration mistake, just go to the api-config.ts and set the correct verb, and the `call` method will use the correct verb.

Comment: Changing from a array to a dictionary is a needed improvement

Comment: Finally think of the api-config similar to a postman file, that is a list of endpoints, verbs, they have no idea if the endpoints are on certain service, in this approach they are grouped together because of the naming convention <SERVICE_ACTION> in the api-config file

Comment: ..also `api-config` is separated to make adding a new endpoint simple and reduce the posibility of messing up with the BaseService implementation, that file could eventually just be a JSON file